Problem with gsap on mobile version when deployed
I have concern with gsap animations on mobile version(s).
More specifically:

Local, the code works perfectly on both destop and mobile version(s)

When deployed, the code still works on desktop and on the responsive simulator that desktop chrome proposes.
But the gsap animations do no work on mobile versions.


I tried the different methods to link gsap and my code, and the results are always those described above.
Does someone have an idea to help me?
Thanks in advance!
Didier
